# Setting Boundaries to ReorderableListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-reorderable-listview

How to set a boundary to the dragging of the Child Widget inside `ReorderableListView`

Current Output : -

[image]

Expected Output : -

Draggable Child Widget should not move further than the blue `Container` Widget.

Code to reproduce the issue : -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const ReorderableApp());

class ReorderableApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReorderableApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('ReorderableListView Sample')),
        body: const ReorderableExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ReorderableExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReorderableExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<ReorderableExample> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<ReorderableExample> {
  final List<int> _items = List<int>.generate(20, (int index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        color: Colors.blue[100],
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Center(
          child: ReorderableListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
            children: <Widget>[
              for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index += 1)
                Container(
                  key: Key('$index'),
                  height: 60,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  color: Colors.blue[400],
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text('Item ${_items[index]}'),
                ),
            ],
            onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
              setState(() {
                if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                  newIndex -= 1;
                }
                final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
                _items.insert(newIndex, item);
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it touch-device focused ? or just desktop will be ok

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, since my app is for desktop and mobile devices. I require both the function

Comment: @EmreKaratopuk, I did not find a prefect solution. You can check the workaround by in the answer section.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, after lot of research, I found a solution for this requirement with `Overlay` and `OverlayEntry`

Here is a code

```dart
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<ReorderableExample> {
  final List<int> _items = List<int>.generate(20, (int index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        color: Colors.blue[100],
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Overlay(
          initialEntries: [OverlayEntry(
            builder: (context) {
              return Center(
                child: Builder(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return ReorderableListView(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index += 1)
                          Container(
                            key: Key('$index'),
                            height: 60,
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            color: Colors.blue[400],
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text('Item ${_items[index]}'),
                          ),
                      ],
                      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
                        setState(() {
                          if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                            newIndex -= 1;
                          }
                          final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
                          _items.insert(newIndex, item);
                        });
                      },
                    );
                  }
                ),
              );
            }
          )],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Really interesting while work on this kind of task. Thanks @Ramji

Comment: Alex, your code creates an overlay when it is dragged out of the border, the topmost or bottom Widget should not be able to drag outside that area, anyways since no one has answered yet and the bounty is about to expire I am giving you the bounty for answering a workaround but I can't accept this as a perfect answer.